# Call PHP Function inside ECHO inside Function

Tags: php

```
function footer(){
    echo "
    <script src='<?php echo JS_DIR ?>/nav.min.js'></script>
    ";
}
```

Is there a way I can call this JS_DIR function from within a php echo, or alternately output:

```
<script src='<?php echo JS_DIR ?>/nav.min.js'></script>
```

...from the footer function?

Comment: You don't need to nest `<?php ?>` (and you indeed _cannot_). Concatenate in your constant.  `echo '<script src=' . JS_DIR . '>/nav....></script>';`

Comment: Did you try using normal PHP syntax, such as echo "<script src='".JS_DIR;

Comment: It seems that most people did not catch the part where JS_DIR is a function;  The way you asked the question makes JS_DIR look like a constant.

Comment: @BinaryAlchemist I'm guessing this is actually mistaken terminology and `JS_DIR` really is a constant rather than a function...

Comment: @BinaryAlchemist sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
function footer(){
    echo "
    <script src='".JS_DIR()."/nav.min.js'></script>
    ";
}
```

The double quote (") stops the string literal, and the period (.) concats (adds/appends) the output of your JS_DIR() function to the string. The second period and double quote appends the string literal, '/nav.min.js'>' to your output.

Answer (score 1):

is that what you mean?

```
function footer(){
    echo "<script src='". JS_DIR() ."/nav.min.js'></script>";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function footer(){
    echo '<script src="'.JS_DIR.'/nav.min.js"></script>';
}
```

Comment: JS_DIR is a function, not a constant. The above won't work